# Netbeans Double Click file in File Explorer (Project Explorer)

Tags: netbeans, graphics-tablet, double-click

Am I the only one who has trouble double clicking on a file to open it in NetBeans?

I use a Bamboo Fun pen tablet, and I have a button on the side to double-click. When I press it the pen moves, *maybe a pixel* left or right. This somehow doesn't get recognized as a double click and it's infuriating.

Any other program would count two clicks on the same *icon* as a double click.  Is there any way to fix this? It's absolutely my biggest gripe with the program, other than the fact that they don't use the native Windows Open File dialog...

Comment: Does this behaviour occur with the mouse?

Comment: If you were to move the mouse slightly, I imagine so.  I don't have a mouse at work, only this pen.  However, the pen is so light it's easy to slightly shift it while depressing the button.  The fact that the threshold for moving the mouse is seemingly 1 pixel is so frustrating.

Comment: If I hold the pen *perfectly* still, it works.

Comment: Might I suggest turning the sensitivity down on the tablet or borrowing a mouse from your IT dept to at least discount a hardware issue?

Comment: This is not a hardware issue.  This is a software issue.  Every other program works fine, it's the way they programmed how they listen for double clicks.  I was wondering if someone else ran into this problem, and possibly knew of a setting I could change in Netbeans, or an add-on or something.  I AM the IT department.